# CKAN: Harvest with custom schema

Tags: ckan

I have two CKAN 2.7.4 instances. Both use the same schema with custom fields added to the dataset schema as per http://docs.ckan.org/en/2.7/extensions/adding-custom-fields.html

I have setup a harvest from A to B using the `ckanext-harvest` extension and the default CKAN Source type.

Only the CKAN core fields are transferred across when harvesting.

Is this expected behaviour for the default CKAN harvester? Does it require a custom harvester to bring across the custom dataset schema fields?

I did notice in `ckanext-harvest/ckanext/harvest/harvesters/base.py` ~ line  276:

`schema = default_create_package_schema()`

it is using the default package schema - but not sure if I'm misunderstanding this.

Any info or experiences greatly appreciated.

Many thanks.